# jQuery slideDown select certain element?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a jQuery function that performs slideDown anitmation on a certain element when clicked like this

```
$('.Minimize').click(function() {
            $('.ContentTD').slideUp('slow', function() {
                //animation complete
            });
        });
```

the above script is written inside a web user control.

the problem is  that if a page has many instances of the control, the slideDown function is executed in all the instances in the page.

I want the function to be executed only in the control I click.

how to do this ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can climb up to the container they're both in and find the element relatively, like this:

```
$('.Minimize').click(function() {
   $(this).closest('.container').find('.ContentTD').slideUp('slow');
});
```

This assumes markup something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <button class="Minimize">Minimize</button>
  <div class="ContentTD">Content</div>
</div>
```

As long as both are inside some container with a class or other attribute you can identify, you can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the `.ContentTD` only in *that* container.  Or, if they're siblings like the simple example above, [`.siblings('.ContentTD')`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) works, or some *other* [tree traversal method](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/), the point is to use `$(this)` (the `.Minimize` you clicked on) and find the element relative to that.

Comment: Thanks Nick it's exactly what I wanted